# ASP.NET return FileResult action and website slows

Tags: performance

My website is apparently becoming very slow to access with only around 20 people is currently downloading from my website. My website provide large file around 100MB to download, so these 20 people is currently downloading from it.

When enough people is downloading, the website becomes inaccessible, basically when I try to browse the page, it loads for a long time before appearing. I do below

```
FileLocation fl = _store.GetFileLocation(id);
if (fl == null) return;
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fl.Location) == false) return;
RangeDownloader rd = new RangeDownloader(fl.Location, new FileInfo(fl.Location));
rd.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
```

The RangeDownloader class is basically a class to allow range download (multi section/multi part).

Am I doing anything wrong here? Must I use separate thread for providing download, meaning that I use ThreadStart? Isn't each request to the website is a separate process? Do I really need to use threading? Is 20 person downloading from my shared hosting plan considered as heavy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, FIleContent does not slow down the ASP.NET pool however it consumes process, when too many user hit the same file, the server may be slowed down, this also happen in other web server.